# Проблема считывания бинарного файла, вылетает исключение

Tags: c#

```
using (var br = new BinaryReader(File.Open("bw.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), Encoding.ASCII))
{
  Numr = br.ReadInt32();                 //количество записей, первая строка в файле
  for (int i = 0; i < Numr; i++)
  {
      StArray[i].Mark = br.ReadString(); //в строке вылетает исключение "Index out of range"
      StArray[i].Year = br.ReadInt32();
      StArray[i].Volume = (float) br.ReadDouble();
      StArray[i].Mileage = br.ReadInt32();                    
  }
 }
```

Comment: Вы не создали видимо массив StArray, либо его размер меньше количества строк.

Comment: Массив создан, до этого он используется множество раз и очень даже успешно, размер его фиксированный - количество элементов, значение которых увеличивается при добавлении в массив элемента и уменьшается при удалении, бинарный файл, что идёт на запись это массив структур, первая строка - количество элементов, далее по 4 идут записи

Comment: Такого рода ошибки исправляются самим программистом с помощью отладки. Поставьте точку останова на строку `for(..)` и проверьте состояние массива `StArray`.

Comment: первая *строка* в файле - у вас точно *бинарный* файл? ReadInt32 читает первые **четыре байта**, а не первую строку. Если у вас количество элементов записано в первой строке, текстом - то стоит читать файл как текстовый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Index out of range` означает что вы пытаетесь обратиться к элементу массива который не существует, больше максимального индекса.

То есть размер вашего массива меньше чем количество итераций вашего цикла.

Для отладки таких вещей лучше всего подходит отладчик. Ставите точку останова на строке на которой выпадает ошибка и изучаете.

В вашем случае смотрите текущее `i`, и общую длину массива.

```
Numr = br.ReadInt32();
```

Это не очень хороший подход к записи файла (не во всех ситуациях но наиболее часто), так как по каким-то причинам (возможно у вас так и есть) туда может попасть число которое не соответствует реальному количеству элементов.

Посмотрите в сторону решения считывать до достижения конца файла.